# Intersection observer Cannot read property 'current' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to implement `IntersectionObserver` on my project but I receive an error `Cannot read property 'current' of undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

**useOnScreen.js**

```
const useOnScreen = ({ref, rootMargin = "0px", }) => {
 const [isIntersecting, setIntersecting ] = useState(false);

 useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
        ([entry]) => {
            setIntersecting(entry.isIntersecting)
        },
        {
            rootMargin,
        }
    );
    if(ref.current) {
        observer.observe(ref.current);
    }

    return () => {
        observer.unobserve(ref.current)
    }
 }, [])

 return isIntersecting;
};

export default useOnScreen;
```

**App.js**

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
import useOnScreen from './useOnScreen';


const App = ()
  const ref = useRef();
  const onScreen = useOnScreen(ref);
  
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
       onScreen ? "AAAAA" : "BBBBBB" 
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that on the initial render, `ref` will be `undefined` and you are trying to access a property on it. You can update your check like this:

```
if (ref?.current) {
  observer.observe(ref.current);
}
```

or this:

```
if (ref && ref.current) {
  observer.observe(ref.current);
}
```